# Tikz package: how to treat cells of a table as nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I'm new to the `tikz` package and I'm looking to make a figure that treats the cells of a table as nodes. This is what I'm going for:

[image]

Comment: Have you read the TikZ documentation?  §20 Matrices and alignment and §57 Matrix Library shows how to make a `[matrix of nodes]`.  Once you had a go at that, post a minimal document showing what's not working and we can help you with that.

Comment: The `tikz` package basically ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\nodepart`.

Here is the beginning of your image, I leave you the rest as an exercise.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[name=artista, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=6, draw, rectangle split draw splits=false, align=center] 
    { Artist A
        \nodepart{two} User 1: 74 plays
        \nodepart{three} User 2: 32 plays
        \nodepart{four} User 3: 0 plays
        \nodepart{five} $\vdots$
        \nodepart{six} User \emph{n}: 67 plays
    };
    \draw (artista.text split west) -- (artista.text split east);

    \node[rectangle,draw, right = of artista] (bm251) {BM25}; 
    \draw [red] (artista.two east) -- (bm251.west);
    \draw [red] (artista.three east) -- (bm251.west);
    \draw [red] (artista.four east) -- (bm251.west);
    \draw [red] (artista.six east) -- (bm251.west);

    \node[name=artistb, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=6, draw, rectangle split draw splits=false, align=center, below = of artista] 
    { Artist B
        \nodepart{two} User 1: 95 plays
        \nodepart{three} User 2: 0 plays
        \nodepart{four} User 3: 129 plays
        \nodepart{five} $\vdots$
        \nodepart{six} User \emph{n}: 56 plays
    };
    \draw (artistb.text split west) -- (artistb.text split east);

    \node[rectangle,draw, right = of artistb] (bm252) {BM25}; 
    \draw [red] (artistb.two east) -- (bm252.west);
    \draw [red] (artistb.three east) -- (bm252.west);
    \draw [red] (artistb.four east) -- (bm252.west);
    \draw [red] (artistb.six east) -- (bm252.west);

    \node[green, draw, thick, text width=50pt, font={\tiny\bfseries}, text=black, below =9ex of bm251](between12) {Each user\\ receive a score\\ from the BM25\\ function};

    \draw[->, green] (between12) -- (bm251);
    \draw[->, green] (between12) -- (bm252);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `matrix`, based/converted on/from *CarLaTeX* answer:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[BM/.style = {%Big Matrix
                        matrix of nodes, draw, inner sep=0pt,
                        nodes={minimum width=#1, inner sep=1mm}
                                    },
                        node distance = 6mm and 12mm
                        ]
\matrix (m11) [BM=19ex]
{ Artist A                  \\
  User 1: 74 plays          \\
  User 2: 32 plays          \\
  User 3: 0 plays           \\
  $\vdots$                  \\
  User \emph{n}: 67 plays   \\
};
  \draw (m11-1-1.south west) -- (m11-1-1.south east);
%
\node (bm25a) [rectangle, draw, right = of m11] {BM25};
\draw[red]  (m11-2-1.east) -- (bm25a.west)
            (m11-3-1.east) -- (bm25a.west)
            (m11-4-1.east) -- (bm25a.west)
            (m11-6-1.east) -- (bm25a.west);
%
\matrix (m12) [BM=24ex, right=of bm25a]
{ Artist A (BM25 score)     \\
  User 1: 10.54             \\
  User 2: 12.81             \\
  User 3: \,\ 3.79            \\
  $\vdots$                  \\
  User \emph{n}: 11.67      \\
};
  \draw (m12-1-1.south west) -- (m12-1-1.south east);
%
\draw[red,->]  (bm25a) -- (m12);
%%%% second row with matrces
\matrix (m21) [BM=19ex, below=of m11]
{ Artist B                  \\
  User 1: 95 plays          \\
  User 2: 0 plays           \\
  User 3: 129 plays          \\
  $\vdots$                  \\
  User \emph{n}: 56 plays   \\
};
  \draw (m21-1-1.south west) -- (m21-1-1.south east);
%
\node (bm25b) [rectangle,draw, right = of m21] {BM25};
\draw[red]  (m21-2-1.east) -- (bm25b.west)
            (m21-3-1.east) -- (bm25b.west)
            (m21-4-1.east) -- (bm25b.west)
            (m21-6-1.east) -- (bm25b.west);
%%%%
\path(bm25a) -- node (between12) [draw=green, thick, 
                                  align=left, 
                                  font=\scriptsize\bfseries] {Each user\\ receive a score\\ 
                                                        from the BM25\\ function}
     (bm25b);
\draw[->, green] (between12) -- (bm25a);
\draw[->, green] (between12) -- (bm25b);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]